# Craft doesn't recognize Snipcart plugin

Tags: install

I'm following this tutorial ([Managing Your Craft Inventory Using Snipcart Webhooks](https://snipcart.com/blog/managing-your-craft-inventory-using-snipcart-webhooks)) and have downloaded the repository from GitHub and cloned. The folder was created without inconvenient but is still not recognized in the admin dashboard

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename that `snipcart-craft-webhooks-plugins` folder to `snipcartwebhooks` in order for Craft to recognize it.